# Does C++11 atomic automatically solve multi-core race on variable read-write?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, cpu-cores

I know that `atomic<T>` will apply a lock on type "T" variable when multiple threads are reading and writing the variable, making sure only one of them is doing the R/W.

But in a multi-CPU core computer, threads can run on different cores, and different cores would have different L1-cache, L2-cache, while share L3-cache. We know sometimes C++ compiler will optimize a variable to be stored inside register, so that if a variable is not stored in memory, then there's no memory synchronization between different core-cache on the variable.

If an `atomic<T>` variable is optimized to be some register variable by compiler, then it's not stored in memory, when one core writes its value, another core could read out a stale value, right? Is there any guarantee on this data consistency?

Comment: This is kind of `std::atomic`'s raison d'etre. Note that it doesn't necessarily take a lock, though. There's even a test for that built into the type.

Comment: Please provide some example code that represents a potentially problematic case, where the compiler could miscompile an atomic variable.

Comment: Near duplicate: [Can the compiler optimize out accesses with memory order relaxed that are not ordered by any memory fence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75860758) - compilers can't optimize `atomic` variables into registers.  (Unless they're local variables that no other thread could have a reference to, then it would be legal but current compilers choose not to.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atomic doesn't "solve" things the way you vaguely describe.  It provides certain very specific guarantees onvolving consistency of memory based on order.

Various compilers implement these guarantees in different ways on different platforms.

On x86/64 no locks are used for atomic integers and pointers up to a reasonable size.  And the hardware provises stronger guarantees than the standard requires, making some of the more esoteric options equivalent to full consistency.

I won't be able to fully answer your question but I can point you in the right direction; the topic you need to learn about is "the C++ memory model".

That being said, atomics exist in order to avoid the exact problem you describe.  If you ask for full memory order consistency, and thread A modifies X then Y, no other thread can see Y modified but not X.  How that guarantee is provided is not specified by the C++ standard; cache line invalidation, using special instructions for access, barring certain register-based optimizations by the compiler, etc are all the kind of thing that compilers do.

Note that the C++ memory model was refined, bugfixed and polished for C++17 in order to describe the behaviour of the new parallel algorithms and permit their efficient implementation on GPU hardware (among other spots) with the right flags, and in turn it influenced the guarantees that new GPU hardware provides.  So people talking about memory models may be excited and talk about more modern issues than your mainly C++11 concerns.

This is a big complex topic.  It is really easy to write code you think is portable, yet only works on a specific platform, or only usually works on the platform you tested it on.  But that is just because threading is hard.

Comment: @curious I said that where?  Programs do via instructions.  Here is an analysis of atomic x86 instructions: https://spcl.inf.ethz.ch/Research/Parallel_Programming/Atomics/

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for this:

> **[intro.progress]/18** An implementation should ensure that the last value (in modification order) assigned by an atomic or synchronization operation will become visible to all other threads in a finite period of time.

Comment: Note that "should" in standardese means "this is a good idea, but it's not required".

Comment: @PeteBecker: Yes, but in this case it just means they don't have a formal way to phrase it.  There's also similar phrasing about "reasonable" amount of time for visibility in another part of the standard.  In terms of the OP's question, a C++ implementation for a machine with private registers and cache-coherent shared memory (like all real-world cores that we run threads across) must not optimize an `atomic` variable into registers.  (Unless it's a local  variable that no other threads could have a reference to.)

Comment: @PeterCordes -- I have no idea what your point is. "Should" does not impose a requirement. Full stop.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I'm saying that I think the authors of the standard would make this a "must" formal requirement if they could find a way to phrase it that was compatible with formal verification.  I know that's the case for the out-of-thin-air values part (*[What formally guarantees that non-atomic variables can't see out-of-thin-air values and create a data race like atomic relaxed theoretically can?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56673990)* cites some evidence from other stuff the committee has written).

Comment: @PeteBecker: The other half of my point is that no sane implementation could violate this (in the way the OP means) and still be usable.  "Optimizations" that introduce potentially-infinite waits or deadlocks must be considered invalid (*[How C++ Standard prevents deadlock in spinlock mutex with memory\_order\_acquire and memory\_order\_release?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61299704)*).

Comment: @PeteBecker: I suspect the reason this is just a "should" not a "must" is that with enough contention, a non-fair scheduler could starve a thread indefinitely, and they don't want to force C++ implementations (OS + compiler) to avoid stuff like that.  But turning a `while(!ready){}` spin-wait into `if(!ready) while(1){}` at compile time isn't something you should expect from any C++ compiler.  Perhaps a Deathstation 9000 could do that and still claim ISO C++ compliance, but for reasons like this, that level of compliance is not sufficient for practical usability.

Comment: Oh, I already wrote an answer on [Can the compiler optimize out accesses with memory order relaxed that are not ordered by any memory fence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75860758) which explains why I don't think the "should" wording is a cause for concern when writing real programs.  This question is a near duplicate of it.

Comment: @PeterCordes -- so your point is that on most real-world systems that's not an issue. Fine. But be clear: that's not because the standard mandates it. There is nothing to comply with, because there is no requirement.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Yes, agreed.  But I was worried that some future readers would take your comment as saying this was something you might have to worry about in practice *for the purposes of this question* (about compilers keeping atomic values in registers), based on the tone, phrasing, and context of your comment.

Comment: Keeping atomic values in registers across multiple modifications and reads (even with `relaxed`) may also be forbidden by other rules, like the coherency requirements involving the modification-order for each atomic variable separately.  (http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#19)

Comment: @PeterCordes -- this answer (did you read it?) talks **only** about the C++ standard; my comment is **only** about the C++ standard. There was no confusion until you added all your noise.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Did you read the question it's answering?  It's asking about normal real CPUs (and compilers) and how the standard applies to them.  But I don't think we're going to agree on this; I've said all I think is useful for future readers, and there's no point in us going in circles further.

Comment: @PeterCordes -- my comment, obviously, addresses **this answer**. If I meant to comment on the question I would have commented on the question.